# range search and create worksheet with specific string name

Tags: vba, excel

i wanted to search the input stored in the cells from userform  and if the value is available then the sub will exit else the code should create a worksheet with the string name. the full code looks something like this:

```
Public CE_LASTROW_PNO_CHK, i As Integer
Public PNO As String
Sub CMD_CEENTRYOK_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'Make CE_MASTER_DATA active
    CE_MASTER_DATA.Activate
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Determine emptyRow
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Transfer information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = "P-" & CE_P_MID.Value & "-" & CE_P_LAST.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = UNIT.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = CE_PHASE.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = CE_DISCRIPTION.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = CE_ENTRY_RCVD_DD.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = CE_ENTRY_RCVD_MM.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = CE_ENTRY_RCVD_YYYY.Value
Call CE_EXISTING_PNO_CHK
End Sub
'check for the existing P-No
Sub CE_EXISTING_PNO_CHK()

CE_LASTROW_PNO_CHK = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) - 1
CE_LASTROW_PNO_CHK = CE_LASTROW_PNO_CHK + 1

    For i = 1 To CE_LASTROW_PNO_CHK
     If Sheets("CE_MASTER_DATA").Cells(1, i) = "P-" & CE_P_MID.Value & "-" & 
CE_P_LAST.Value Then
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        MsgBox (" Project already exists")
     Exit Sub
    End If
Next i
Call CreateSheet
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Unload Me
End Sub

 Sub CreateSheet()
For Each Worksheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Worksheet.Name = PNO Then
    Exit Sub ' if found - exit sub
    End If
Next Worksheet
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = PNO
End Sub
```

the user form looks like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czYrB.png) the problem is ether the counter is not working properly or what i cant debug it properly. also the check for the existing worksheet is giving error.

any help will be much appreciated

Comment: CE_LASTROW_PNO_CHK = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) - 1  gives me a zero.  Try putting a stopping point on the If Sheets("CE_MASTER_DATA").Cells line and see if execution stops there.  If so, hover over CE_LASTROW_PNO_CHK  and see what value it has.

Comment: Where do you declare/define `CE_P_MID` and `CE_P_LAST`? and all of the other values under `'Transfer Information`?  Also, you never seem to set `PNO` to any value...unless I'm missing something? Are those values in the userform?

Comment: @Brucewayne CE_P_MID and CE_P_LAST and all other variables come from userform as shown in the attached pic. and PNO is concatenated result of CE_P_LAST & CE_P_LAST (string)